# Layouts for 800*480 mdpi set

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an app which is being tested on a device 800*480 resolution but it is an mdpi set and picks resources likewise Micromax Funbook(cheap stuff). http://www.micromaxfunbook.com/

all the layouts gets messed up testing on that device how can I design my layout accordingly.

Comment: 480x800 screen comes under `hdpi`.

Comment: I know but this device is mdpi that is where I am having trouble it's working on other devices with same resolution

Comment: Yes yes. there are many **hacked** devices comes with exact resolution  but wrong dpi (not as per the standard).

Comment: why don't you provide resources for `mdpi` and `hdpi` screen? In short  resources for almost all the screens.

Comment: I did the needful but the problem is with such screen size tester is not willing to see the mdpi layout all the images,text size (everything that android picks) is mdpi.. That's why we hate testers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create custom `Layout` inside `Rec` Folder.

Create Folder `layout-large-mdpi` and put xml inside. and also put images inside folder `drawable-large-mdpi`

This is work on 800 * 480 resolution with mdpi.

More Refer [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing)

Comment: I solved this problem long time ago but your answer is a really great thanks