# Samsung and micromax tablet both picking assets from mdpi

Tags: resolution, android

I have 2 android tablets - 1 samsung and 1 micromax tablet, samsung has 800 x 1280 pixels, 10.1 inches (~149 ppi pixel density) and micromax has 600 x 1024 pixels, 10.1 inches (~118 ppi pixel density).

I want their assets to be seprate but both are picking from mdpi, How can I do it?

Is it possible to use something like drawable-w600-mdpi and drawable-w800-mdpi?

Answer (score 0):

No. Have a look at the [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) page over at Android Developers. In Table 1 you can find all admissible qualifiers. Personally, I would suggest you let the OS handle the layout and choosing the right resource. However, with the new format of specifying resources 'wdp' respectively 'hdp', you might be able to get what you want as the tablets feature different sizes.

However, unless you have a very good reason to do so, I wouldn't do it. Often when you think you need to do something that is discouraged, there is a flaw in your design or the requirements can be met in an easier, more standard, way.

**Update**:
As by the comments, your problem is probably related to the devices not correctly communicating their DPI and, therefore, Android not choosing the correct resource. [An Android Developer blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html) I recently read details the problem and shows a few examples on how to use the new numeric selectors tied to screen width and height to resolve some of those problems.

Comment: I can not use the same resources for both tablets, they look really bad on one of it.

Comment: By the definition given by Google in the document I linked, below 120dpi the `ldpi` resource is loaded. `hdpi` should start at 240. By what you have given, the smaller tablet should load the ldpi resource and the other one the mdpi resource. Are you sure you have added different resources to the corresponding folders? BTW, are you sure you mean PPI and not DPI? There is a subtle but tangible difference. Search for "Screen pixel density" on the resource I provided above to get a guide on how big the image should be for each resource and how much dpi it should pack.

Comment: That is correct it should be ldpi and that is my problem. thanks for the information I got my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030836/layouts-for-800480-mdpi-set

Comment: You are welcome. However, the answer is outdated. Please use the available heigh and available width to optimise your image. This is recommended for cases where the simple distinction between ldpi and its siblings is not sufficient. I will update my answer to include a link to a blog where the problem is better explained.